# How to call C functions from SQL in Tarantool?

Tags: sql, c, tarantool

How can I call a C-function from SQL in Tarantool?

[Documentation](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/reference_lua/box_schema/#box-schema-func-create-with-body) says:

> C functions are imported from .so files

But where shall I specify the reference to my .so file?

It would be great to see an example.

Comment: In that section is only for Lua Functions . Look at https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/tutorials/c_tutorial/ . I dont nothing about Tarantool but i think enable dev model allow to you create your custom c functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should firstly register your function via `:func.create`:

```
box.schema.func.create("function1.divide", {language = 'C', returns = 'number',
                        is_deterministic = true,
                        exports = {'LUA', 'SQL'}})
```

You can read more info on the subj here: https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/tutorials/c_tutorial/

Then you can use it in SQL:

```
box.execute('SELECT "function1.divide"()')
```

Also you can examine more examples in source code ([test/box/function1.test.lua](https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool/blob/master/test/box/function1.test.lua#L138)).